# Cannot play a video from internal storage with the native codec given by Google using adb

Tags: android, adb, video-player, android-internal-storage

I am using the native codec app given by Google: (https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-codec).
The app has a folder (assets) which contains some video samples to play.
My purpose is to read videos from the internal storage of the phone (i.e /sdcard/filename.mp4).
I added these 2 lines to the manifest file but this hasn't helped to fix the issue yet.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

I modified the code to get the video filename as an argument given by adb shell.
Here is the code:

```
    mSourceString = getIntent().getStringExtra("arg");
    if (!mCreated) {
        if (mSourceString != null) {
            mCreated = createStreamingMediaPlayer(getResources().getAssets(), mSourceString);
        }
    }

    if (mCreated) {
        mIsPlaying = !mIsPlaying;
        setPlayingStreamingMediaPlayer(mIsPlaying);
    }
```

The native code of the method which reads the video filename is the following:

```
jboolean Java_com_example_mohammed_myapplication_MainActivity_createStreamingMediaPlayer(JNIEnv* env,                                                                                   jclass clazz, jobject assetMgr, jstring filename)
{
    LOGV("@@@ create");

    // convert Java string to UTF-8
    const char *utf8 = env->GetStringUTFChars(filename, NULL);
    LOGV("opening %s", utf8);

    off_t outStart, outLen;
    int fd = AAsset_openFileDescriptor(AAssetManager_open(AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetMgr), utf8, 0),
                                       &outStart, &outLen);

    env->ReleaseStringUTFChars(filename, utf8);
    if (fd < 0) {
        LOGE("failed to open file: %s %d (%s)", utf8, fd, strerror(errno));
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    data.fd = fd;

    workerdata *d = &data;

    AMediaExtractor *ex = AMediaExtractor_new();
    media_status_t err = AMediaExtractor_setDataSourceFd(ex, d->fd,
                                                         static_cast<off64_t>(outStart),
                                                         static_cast<off64_t>(outLen));
    close(d->fd);
    if (err != AMEDIA_OK) {
        LOGV("setDataSource error: %d", err);
        return JNI_FALSE;
    }

    int numtracks = AMediaExtractor_getTrackCount(ex);

    AMediaCodec *codec = NULL;

    LOGV("input has %d tracks", numtracks);
    for (int i = 0; i < numtracks; i++) {
        AMediaFormat *format = AMediaExtractor_getTrackFormat(ex, i);
        const char *s = AMediaFormat_toString(format);
        LOGV("track %d format: %s", i, s);
        const char *mime;
        if (!AMediaFormat_getString(format, AMEDIAFORMAT_KEY_MIME, &mime)) {
            LOGV("no mime type");
            return JNI_FALSE;
        } else if (!strncmp(mime, "video/", 6)) {
            // Omitting most error handling for clarity.
            // Production code should check for errors.
            AMediaExtractor_selectTrack(ex, i);
            codec = AMediaCodec_createDecoderByType(mime);
            AMediaCodec_configure(codec, format, d->window, NULL, 0);
            d->ex = ex;
            d->codec = codec;
            d->renderstart = -1;
            d->sawInputEOS = false;
            d->sawOutputEOS = false;
            d->isPlaying = false;
            d->renderonce = true;
            AMediaCodec_start(codec);
        }
        AMediaFormat_delete(format);
    }

    mlooper = new mylooper();
    mlooper->post(kMsgCodecBuffer, d);

    return JNI_TRUE;
}
```

The app plays the videos successfully when they are in the "assets" folder, i.e inside the app. But when a video is outside the app (internal/external storage) the app stops working.

Is there a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Apart from adding storage permission, the user needs to give manual permission also.

For testing purpose, you can go to Settings-> Apps-> your app-> Permissions-> enable storage permission. Should work fine then.

For production purpose, you should ask for permission via dialogue. There are plenty of tutorials for that.